# Why do I get a 404 error on my custom post type archive pagination?

Tags: php, custom-post-types, pagination, html

When I try to set up pagination on my custom post type archive page I get a 404 if I click on the next page. The first page works fine. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```php
<?php get_header();

?>

<div class="archive-header">
    <h1>
        Tesxt
    </div>


<?php
    $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'jobs', 'paged' => (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1, 'posts_per_page' => 2 ) );
    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
            <div <?php post_class(); ?>>
                        <article>
                        <div class="ort">
                                <?php 
                                    $ort = get_field('ort');
                                if( $ort ): ?>
                                    <h4><?php echo esc_html( $ort->name ); ?></h4>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>
                            
                        </article>
                </div>
        <?php endwhile;

        $total_pages = $loop->max_num_pages;
        if ($total_pages > 1){
            $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
            echo paginate_links( array(
                'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),
                'format' => '?paged=%#%',
                'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
                'total' => $loop->max_num_pages
            ) );
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();

    endif;


get_footer();

?>
```

Comment: I see you've ignored the main query and added a new second query via `WP_Query` instead of modifying the original using `pre_get_posts`. This would have sidestepped your problem entirely, _and_ given you a nice speed/performance boost. Was there a specific reason you avoided this? It looks like you could have used a generic `archive-jobs.php` then used a tiny filter in `functions.php` to force it to 2 jobs per page

Comment: @TomJNowell I just didn't know the best way I think. Also it was a bit tricky to get an archive template to work as the home page because it always was showing no data. (Presumably because the WP-Query was used for the home page itself already)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why Does It Happen?

It's because the number of pages in your second `WP_Query` is larger than the number of pages in the main query.

So if there are 8 jobs, that's 4 pages in your custom query, and 1 page in the main query. So when you go to page 2 *there is no page 2 in the *main query* resulting in a 404*. This isn't a problem when using `pre_get_posts` which modifies the main query instead of creating a second one.

### A Solution

If you remove the custom `WP_Query` you can revert to a standard main post loop, and standard pagination.

Then, to enforce the 2 jobs per page requirement, you can use `pre_get_posts` to filter the main query before it goes to the database and add `posts_per_page`:

```php
// Lets modify the parameters on the main query
// whenever you create a WP_Query this runs, including the main query! ( aka $q )
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'only_2_jobs_per_page' );
function only_2_jobs_per_page( \WP_Query $q ) : void {
    // we only want to change the frontend job post archives
    if ( is_admin() || ! $q->is_main_query() || ! is_post_type_archive( 'jobs' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // we only want 2 jobs per page:
    $q->set( 'posts_per_page', 2 );
}
```

With that your pagination will work without any of the weird hacks needed for a custom `WP_Query`, your code is simpler, **and it'll be twice as fast!**

This means that this code:

```php
    $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'jobs', 'paged' => (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1, 'posts_per_page' => 2 ) );
    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
```

Becomes:

```php
    if ( have_posts() ) :
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

And this code:

```php
        $total_pages = $loop->max_num_pages;
        if ($total_pages > 1){
            $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
            echo paginate_links( array(
                'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),
                'format' => '?paged=%#%',
                'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
                'total' => $loop->max_num_pages
            ) );
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
```

Becomes just:

```php
        echo paginate_links();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is exactly what I needed. I wasn't aware of `pre_get_posts` but I learned something new. When would you say a second `WP_Query` would make sense?

I also changed the code a bit to make the archive work as the home page.



`// home page
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'home_jobs_per_page' );
function home_jobs_per_page( \WP_Query $query ) : void {
    if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() || ! is_home() ) {
        return;
    }
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 2 );
 $query->set('post_type', array( 'jobs' ) );
}`

Comment: additional `WP_Query`'s are useful for when you want to show additional information, e.g in a sidebar, widget, shortcode, block etc, or in a footer/header. Always try to use the main query for the main thing to get the maximum performance. Good job on the homepage filter, that's exactly what it's there for :)